# Issue to create function when inside ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) (function(i) {
    jQuery('#skin_'+i).click( function() {
        var result = $('#idskin_'+i).val();             
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: { 'dataString': result },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#loader").show();
            },
            success: function(output_string){ 

                                $("#1").css({
                background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
                border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
                });                 
                $("#2").css({
                background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
                border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
                });                 
                $("#3").css({
                background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
                border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
                });

                                 } // End of success function of ajax form
         });        
      });
   })(i); //for
});
```

Everything works fine, until I attempt to create a function inside this ajax function like this (I will point just the success block of code):

```
            success: function(output_string){ 

            jQuery.exists = function exists(){ 

            $("#1").css({
            background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
            border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
            });                 
            $("#2").css({
            background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
            border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
            });                 
            $("#3").css({
            background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
            border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
            });

                }); //end of custom function

                             } // End of success function of ajax form
```

The webpage just shows as blank, I do not know what might be happening. If this is not possible to do, is there any other way around it ?

Comment: `jQuery.exists = function() {` you dont name an anonymous/closure function.

Comment: There is no such thing like AJAX function. This is a regular callback function, use your browsers debugger to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 syntax errors.. Change the code to:

```
jQuery.exists = function(){ // don't give it the name again

    $("#1").css({
            background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
            border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
    });                 
    $("#2").css({
            background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
            border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
    });                 
    $("#3").css({
            background: "url("+output_string['textu']+")",
            border: "1px solid "+output_string['color']
    });

} // you only need curly here not })
```

Comment: yea buddy I had a syntax error I just fixed. Thanks for the support.